# Вывод переменной в echo

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, столкнулась с проблемой. Вот суть! Вот сам код который прописан в php (в echo намного больше кода, просто урезала, оставив одну строчку в которой проблема)

```
echo " <div id='cover_container' style='background:url('cover_img/$cover_img');'>";
```

Вот что выводит интерпритатор

```
<div id="cover_container" style="background:url("cover_img="" 123villo.png');'="">
```

Должен же выводить

```
 <div id="cover_container" style="background:url("cover_img/123villo.png')">
```

Comment: У вас какая-то путаница с кавычками, разберитесь сначала с ними.

Comment: эта строчка или значение переменной из БД приходит?

Answer (score 2):

Измените свой код на:

```
echo "<div id=\"cover_container\" style=\"background: url('cover_img/{$cover_img}');\">";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo " <div id=\"cover_container\" style=\"background:url('cover_img/$cover_img')\">";
```

Comment: Выше тоже самое написал :D